# How to configure VIM Code completion with ctags and fzf

Tags: vim, autocomplete, ctags, exuberant-ctags, fzf

It is possible to configure fzf in vim insert mode to do code completion? The tags are generated and setup to work with vim. In vim omni completion is working well. But omni completion doesn't have support for fuzzy search. So i am looking for a way to use fzf to do code completion using the tags.

As per the fzf documentation, *fzf#vim#complete is a helper function for creating custom fuzzy completion using fzf*. How can we configure fzf to take the tags as input?